Does turborepo monorepo tool have mechanism like lerna or nx to work without "workspaces":[] in package.json
I have a project which have packages like following
└── packages
    ├── components
    ├── core
    ├── react-native-1
    ├── react-native-2
    └── react-native-3

I was using this for quite a while and was using lerna with nx and now, as company is using turborepo for the same project but on web, we are asked if turborepo is viable for mobile. I tried it out, but the first thing i encountered as soon as started the switch process, turborepo not recognizing the packages, without workspaces, and no option in turbo.json to provide package names. I am not against workspaces, but needing to keep node_modules seperate for each package is a necessity, because there has been issues which became too big in the past because of node_modules mix-ups.
Is there a way turbo can be used without workspaces or we have to stay with nx.
I did gave workspaces a go, but as soon as I completed install other issue arose.
Turbo not have exec like lerna exec which was another need in the project.
